# Отключается Apache в Denwer после запуска

Tags: apache, denwer

После переустановки запустил denwer, но после 30 сек Apache отключается.

Пишет:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 163 of
>   /user/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load
>   /user/local/php5/php5apach2_2.dll into server: \xcd\xe5
>   \xed\xe0\xe9\xe4\xed .....

В свое время я обновил версию php до версии 5.5 и пришлось пошаманить, чтоб он начал работать. Теперь как я понимаю опять нужно, но я не помню что именно нужно сделать.

Comment: Т.е. пока вы не запустите денвер mysql работает нормально? А логи mysql смотрели, там что-нибудь написано про причину остановки?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее за все какое-то приложение занимает порт 3306, на котором MySQL работает. 
В консоли:

```
netstat -a -b -p tcp
```

И узнаешь, какое именно. 
А вообще, не рекомендую использовать денвер. Wamp или Xampp в разы лучше. И разобраться очень просто.